# How to access a symlink pointing to a place outside the share?

Tags: file-sharing, server.app, symlink

I have a share on Lion Server, and a symlink pointing to a directory outside the share. The symlink is working properly when user is logged into the machine via ssh (so permissions are fine), but when  accessing the filesystem via AFP or CIFS, the link is broken.

Is there a setting that allows to follow symlinks outside shared folders?

Comment: Did you try to share the specific file (the target of the symlink) directly?

Comment: No, because I'd prefer to limit the number of shares on the server

Comment: Ah, wait, you have the symlink in a shared folder on the server and the symlink points to a physical file outside the share, correct?

Comment: exactly (points to a folder but doesn't matter)

Comment: I don't think it is possible with CIFS (Windows Sharing) or NFS, because a symlink gives a hint on how to find the target file/folder, but since it is located outside the share it can't be found. You could try *hard linking* with `ln -d` but it didn't work for me (see `man ln` for details). Is it possible to share the folder as a WebDAV share? I guess it would then be possible to configure Apache to follow symlinks... (see http://superuser.com/questions/244245/how-do-i-get-apache-to-follow-symlinks).